# Annoying disk checking every time in booting process

Tags: disk-check

I encounter a problem on booting process. It seems like a disk checking, cleaning etc., but on every boot is just too annoying.

Here is the image I shot at the booting process:
[image]

I remember yesterday I did something to Ubuntu with the purpose to repair wake up problem after suspend (though unsuccessful), what I did is:

In a terminal run `sudoedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix` and paste in the following script. Afterwards make it executable by running `sudo chmod u+x /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix`

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script kills autofs when going into standby to eliminate issues with it
case $1 in

suspend)
#suspending to RAM
    chvt 1
    echo "Going to sleep"
    sleep 1
;;
resume)
#resume from suspend 
    echo "try to resume"
    sleep 1
    chvt 7
;;       
esac
```

After that I tested suspend Ubuntu but Ubuntu failed to wake up. Then I wanted to make the above file not executable by using `chmod -R -x /etc/pm/sleep.d/fglrx-fix`, but I was told I don't have permission to do it. Then I cut off all the text in the above file and saved.

That is what I did. How should I do now so that it won't check the disk every time the system boots. It is really very annoying. Thanks a lot for your help.

PS: 
 1. Should I delete the file fglrx-fix? If yes, how?
 2. I forget to say that the checking time is about 1 min. , not a very long time, but still strange and annoying.
 3. Should I stop force check?

PS2:
21.11.2015 removed the file fglrx-fix, but the problem is still there. Pls help!
[image]

PS3:
I searched the file fsck, this is the result:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31991/discussion-on-question-by-paul333-annoying-disk-checking-every-time-in-booting-p).